# Hashtable for a system with memory constraints

Tags: performance, algorithm, memory-management, data-structures, hashtable

I have read about the variants of hashtable but it is not clear to me which one is more appropriate for a system that is low on memory (we have a memory constraint limit).
Linear/Quadratic probing works well for sparse tables.
I think Double hashing is the same as Quadratic in this aspect.
External chaining does not have issue with clustering.
Most textbooks I have checked seem to assume that a extra space will always be available but practically in most example implementations I have seen since the hashtable is never halved take much more space than really needed.
So which variant of a hashtable is most efficient when we want to make the best usage of memory?

**Update:**
So my question is not only about the size of the buckets. My understanding is that both the size of the buckets **and** the performance under load is what matters. Because if the size of the bucket is small but the table degrades on 50% load then this means we need to resize to a larger table often.

Comment: Have you considered a data structure other than a hashtable?

Comment: @MarkRanson:What other datastructure for searching in constant time can be used?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. However a hash table doesn't necessarily give you constant time as it degrades either. You haven't stepped back to give us the big picture so there's no way to know how alternatives might fare.

Comment: Do you have any external storage available?  It may be necessary to offload the bulk of the hash table while only keeping a small hot subset in memory.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot:Isnt' that an LRU?

Comment: Yup, at my last job we had a four terabyte "hash table" that was stored in Riak, with only the hot subset kept in Redis.  This worked out fairly well in practice.  Ideally you'll be able to fit the entire thing in memory, but offloading may be a good compromise.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot:That is an interesting approach. But I am not talking about a huge dataset but just a small amount of memory

Answer (score 2):

See [this variant](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.5337) of [Cukoo Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).

This will require from you more hash functions, but, it makes sense - you need to pay something for the memory savings.

Comment: In what way is this more efficient? Does it guarantee good performance on a high data load?

Comment: I believe the link explains it. My answer tried to address the specifics of your question, not be a tutorial on this topic.

Comment: But you are talking about the size of the buckets in the table. If the table resizes then where is the benefit? My question is if your suggestion addresses both concerns or not. If it resizes on 50% load then I am not sure I see a difference with the other variants

Comment: See also [this variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch_hashing) of cuckoo hashing

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot:Very interesting. I have to study both more carefully but from a first look, it seems like the buckets are bigger for hopscotch (for bitmap)